# How to check if Referrer URL has URL parameters?

Tags: javascript

I'd like to check if my Referrer URL has parameters in it. Because based on this I'd like to change the url of a button to a different page.

What I have now:

```
var referrer = document.referrer;
var referrerparams = referrer.search;

if (referrerparams) {
 > 'script to change urlbutton.href'
}
```

So I thought i could use both document.referrer and window.location.search, to see if the referrer URL has parameters in it. Independently these two work fine, but not together. I get the following in console: `ƒ search() { [native code] }`.

Does anyoneone know how to check if the Referrer URL has parameters? It doesn't even matter what parameters, just if they exit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a [`URL`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL) object from the referrer and check its `search` property.

```js
const referrerQueryParamStr = new URL(document.referrer).search

if (referrerQueryParamStr) {
    // change urlbutton.href
}
```

If you want the individual key-value pairs in an easy-to-use format, you can use the `searchParams` property instead:

```js
const referrerQueryParams = new URL(document.referrer).searchParams

for (const [key, val] of referrerQueryParams) {
    console.log({ key, val })
}
```

---

> I get the following in console: `ƒ search() { [native code] }`.

This is because `document.referrer` is just a string before you convert it. What you're logging is actually the [`String#search`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/search) function.

```js
typeof document.referrer // string
typeof document.referrer.search // function
document.referrer.search === String.prototype.search // true
```

Comment: Nice, the first option works perfectly for what I need. Thanks!

Comment: It's working perfectly on all other browsers but not working on internet explorer. is there any alternative to achieve the same?

Comment: @KashinathRaut Either use a library like [url](https://www.npmjs.com/package/url) or write your own custom parsing logic (`document.referrer.match(/\?[^#]+/)` or whatever). But a better question is, are you sure you still need to support IE? It's nearing end of life now, and Microsoft is already aggressively pushing Windows 10 users away from it and toward Edge.